# htaccess redirect rule for changing part of url

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to write an htaccess conditional redirect rule, but with no luck so far.

How can I use an htaccess redirect to redirect

```
http://www.domain.tld/en/oldpath/something/
http://www.domain.tld/en/oldpath/somethingelse/
```

to, respectively

```
http://www.domain.tld/en/newpath/something/
http://www.domain.tld/en/oldpath/somethingelse/
```

?

Is there a rule I can use to redirect "oldpath" to "newpath" whatever part of an url precedes or follows it?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^(.*)/oldpath/(.*)$ $1/newpath/$2
```